# ListSliceDensityPlot3D gives wrong plot with specified surfaces

Tags: plotting

First, define

```
data = Flatten[
  Table[{x, y, z, -N@HeavisidePi[1.1 x]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 
    1}, {z, -1, 1, 1}], 2]
```

In which I used `-N@HeavisidePi[1.1 x]`, its plot is

[image]

If I plot this

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"XStackedPlanes", Subdivide[-1, 1, 20]},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This will gives

[image]

This is right.

However If I plot only two surface at x=-0.5 and x=0.5

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"XStackedPlanes", {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

This will give wrong plot

[image]

Only plot one surface is also not right.

```
ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"XStackedPlanes", {-1}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

What is wrong?

I am using Mathematica 10.4.0.0

Comment: Definitely a bug, you can use `Table[]` though, that works.

Comment: @Feyre Hi, Feyre. What do you mean by using `Table[]`?

Comment: It seemed my solution just made the two bugs interfere. To be honest, I don't really think `ListSliceDensityPlot3D` is designed for these circumstances, but I'd report it as a bug.

Comment: @Feyre Thank you for reporting, Feyre.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to this bug, you can specify a color function directly and turn [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) off.

```
With[
 {cf = ColorData[{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", {-1, 0}}]},
 ListSliceDensityPlot3D[data, {"XStackedPlanes", {-0.5, 0.5}},
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cf, {-1, 0}}],
  ColorFunction -> cf,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you JasonB. I just noticed this post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97596/4742    Somehow, I think the problem in that post is quite similar to mine, maybe they are connected. This kind of bug is such a trap! They could easily mislead us into drawing wrong conclusion if we trust Mathematica.